# Keyboard shortcut to jump to closing curly brace or square bracket in json view in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I am using the `JSONViewer` plugin in Notepad++ and viewing many large and nested json elements in a file. What keyboard shortcuts can I use to jump to a `}` or `]`? This would be similar to Visual Studio's <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Place your cursor on the `{` and then type :

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

[Notepad shortcuts](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Notepad-plus-plus_5.9.html)

Comment: The only downside here: it does NOT work dynamically in a recorded macro (Notepad++'s built-in macro recording/playback feature).  It will be treated as a "# of characters navigation", i.e. if your bracket/brace was 10 characters ago, you record this action, then you try to replay it on another line where the brackets are 20 characters apart, the replayed macro will only navigate by 10 characters.  =(   There's no solution to this, and it's not what the OP asked, but I thought it'd be useful for future visitors who use key-shortcuts with macros.

Comment: I wonder if there is a feature that jumps to the start of the PARENT scope instead of switching between the start and end of the scope denoted by the previous open / close brace? Does anyone know? 